# Finding the arcs traversed in Shortest Path (Network Analyst) - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, shortest-path

I used Shortest Path from Network Analyst in ArcGIS to calculate the shortest distances between multiple points. The result I get is the length of the paths, but what I need is the actual route in terms of arcs taken to get from source to destination point. I have read that Shortest Path uses Djikstra's algorithm to calculate these paths, is there any way I could also get the breakdown of these paths that tells me exactly which arcs were traversed to reach from Incident Points to Facility Points?